# Upload Adobe .air file in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, air, adobe, google-cloud-storage

Can google app engine be used to store or host an adobe air file (.air)? The .air file will be used as a software updater. I have tried uploading files view google app engine launcher and the only files uploaded are the php and xml files.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to upload content i.e. your .air files. Just make sure to place those files in the appropriate content folders for your web application and you should be good.

Another option for hosting files as a web site could be Google Drive too. Check out : http://www.labnol.org/internet/host-website-on-google-drive/28178/